# Grab simple info from a PHP file

Tags: php, http, actionscript-3, actionscript

let's say I have a PHP file like this

```
<?php
   echo "Test";
?>
```

Now I want to retrieve the `Test` in an Actionscript 3 code and set it as a variable.

I've been looking at `URLRequest` & `URLLoader` but nothing's actually getting the data for some reason.

Comment: I think you are looking for this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39399633/loading-php-url-in-flash-as3)

Comment: Show your AS3 code.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;

var req:URLRequest = new RLRequest('http://yourserver.com/yourphpfile.php');

req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

loader.load(req);
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,tracedata);

function tracedata(e)
{
     trace('loader.data = '+loader.data);
}
```

Of course, the php file has to be on a server.